# JavaScript: Enlarge and decrease image on scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, resize, addeventlistener

I am trying to resize an image on scroll in javascript with the following conditions:

- The image is close to an upper and lower image that should not resize
- The image has a minimum height of 0, and a max height of almost all screen height
- The image should have height 0 until the lower image is fully seen on screen
- The image should be resized, letting the lower image's position fixed at the bottom, until the upper image reaches the top.
- The image will then start shrinking, and the upper image should be kept at top until the middle image reaches it's minimum size again.

My approach is as follows:

```js
var upperImg = document.getElementById("scroll-sup");
var middleImg = document.getElementById("scroll-int");
var lowerImg = document.getElementById("scroll-inf");
const minHeight = 0;
const maxHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight - 50;

document.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
  var upperRect = upperImg.getBoundingClientRect();
  var lowerRect = lowerImg.getBoundingClientRect();
  var upperDistanceToTop = window.pageYOffset + upperRect.top - 100;
  var delta = Math.floor(e.deltaY);

  if (lowerRect.y > maxHeight + 500 || middleImg.height < minHeight) {
    middleImg.height = minHeight;
  } else if (middleImg.height > maxHeight) {
    middleImg.height = maxHeight;
  } else if (upperRect.top < 60 && middleImg.height > minHeight) {
    middleImg.height -= delta;
    window.scrollBy(0, -delta);
  } else {
    middleImg.height += delta;
  }

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.scroll-img {
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 1000px">some HTML</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <img
    src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sandraparraga/surveillancepower/main/assets/marco_teorico/scroll-sup.png"
    id="scroll-sup"
    class="scroll-img"
  />
  <img
    src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sandraparraga/surveillancepower/main/assets/marco_teorico/scroll-int.png"
    id="scroll-int"
    class="scroll-img"
    style="position: sticky; object-fit: fill"
  />
  <img
    src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sandraparraga/surveillancepower/main/assets/marco_teorico/scroll-inf.png"
    id="scroll-inf"
    class="scroll-img"
  />
</div>
<div style="height: 1000px">some more HTML</div>
```

I fail to see how my code is wrong, but it is not decreasing the image and keeping the upper one in a fixed position.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: please add your HTML to your question and make a snippet out of your html, css and script. much easier to help when theres something to test

Comment: hello @Kinglish. Thanks for pointing this out. I have added the snippet.